# Select time in and time out from fingerprint transaction table according shiftperiod table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have table for shift periods :

```
empoyeeid  ShiftId   PeriodId   Description     DateFrom      DateTo        TimeIn        TimeOut    Night   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  5          9         17        Morning        2014-01-01    2014-12-31     09:00:00     12:59:00    0        
  5          9         18        Night          2014-01-01    2014-12-31     23:00:00     07:00:00    1
```

and table for employee transactions:

```
Employeeid    EventDate    EventTime   EventType
------------------------------------------------
     5        2014-01-02   23:04:29    IN
```

I want to select the period id from first table

I tried this

```
select 
    periodid 
from 
    shifts 
where 
    timein <= eventtime and timein >= eventtime 
    and employeeid = 5
```

Comment: And what would be your expected result set?

Comment: i get the both row for this case ,should be second row "periodid 18" because this is nearest shift for his transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks All**

**abs() function get nearest shift for time in**

```
select  PeriodId from shifts 
where EmployeeCode  = @employeecode 
and datefrom <= @INDat and dateto  >= @INDat
order by abs((cast(DATEPART(HOUR,timein) as int))-(cast(DATEPART(HOUR,@INDat) as int)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select periodid 
from shifts s 
inner join employeeTransactions e
on s.employeeid=e.employeeid
where timein <= eventtime and timeout >=eventtime and e.employeeid=5
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select periodid from shifts join employee on shifts.timein <= employee.eventtime 
and shifts.timein >= employee.eventtime and 
employee.employeeid=5 and employee.employeeid = shifts.employeeid
```